# How to handle stdout from command like "with open() as f:" in python

Tags: python, streaming, paramiko

I am trying to stream large files over ssh, and can currently stream raw files just fine; as in:

```
with open('somefile','r') as f:
  tx.send(filepath='somefile',stream=f.read())
```

tx is a higher level class instance that I have that can stream just fine this way, but I want to be able to use commands like `pv`, `dd`, and `tar` to stream as well.  What I need is:

```
with run_some_command('tar cfv - somefile') as f:
  tx.send(filepath='somefile',stream=f.read())
```

This would take stdout as a stream and write to a remote file.
I've tried doing something like:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['tar','cfv','-','somefile'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
tx.send(filepath='somefile',stream=p.stdout.readall())
```

but to no avail...
I've been googling for a while trying to find an example, but no luck so far.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the only issue is the `.readall()` method, that does not exist.

You can use `p.stdout.read()` to read the entire contents of stdout:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['tar','cfv','-','somefile'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
tx.send(filepath='somefile',stream=p.stdout.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

I walked back and started with a basic example:

```
calc_table_file = '/mnt/condor/proteinlab/1468300008.table'

import subprocess
class TarStream:
  def open(self,filepath):
    p = subprocess.Popen(['tar','cfv','-',filepath], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return(p.stdout)


import paramiko


def writer(stream):
  ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
  ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  ssh.connect('asu-bulk-uspacific', username='labtech', password=password)
  client = ssh.open_sftp()
  with client.open('/mnt/cold_storage/folding.table','w') as f:
    while True:
      data = stream.read(32)
      if not data:
        break
      f.write(data)

## works with normal 'open'
with open(calc_table_file,'r') as f:
  writer(f)

## and popen :)
tar = TarStream()
writer(tar.open(calc_table_file))
```

and it worked!  Thanks for the help.